# how to check and receive result for the api call over jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying hit the API over jquery ajax with the URL and parameter with post method. here I'm checking delivery is available or not for the given Pincode for one of e-com website,please help me out on how to check or receive data from the API response.

My Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').click(function(){
        var api_url = 'http://example.com/webservices/b2cpincodecheck.jsp';
        var key = '4A8DA5E635656'; 
        var pincode = 604408 ;

        if(pincode=="") {
            alert("please enter the pincode");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url:api_url+"?reqid="+key+"&pincode="+pincode,
                dataType: "text/json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result){
                    //console.log(result);
                    if(result) {
                        alert("Delivery is available!");
                    } else {
                        alert("Delivery is not available!");
                    }
                }
            })
        }  
    });
});
</script>
```

As per the API response in the given document, I would get data in XML format

Their response :

```
<response>
<result>successful</result>
<pinCode>604408</pinCode>
<ouCode>abc</ouCode>
</response>
```

Please help me out on how to check or receive data from the API response. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: //console.log(result);

Result here is the API response.

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem, do you want to convert XML in ajax response?

Comment: @FedericaVenuto, in the console, after commenting out I can this  error


jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/awaysellerhidden/prod_details.php?prod_id=5&shop_id=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/webservices/b2cpincodecheck.jsp?reqid=4A8DA5E6CB3F58C8&pincode=577202'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ prod_details.php?pro…id=5&shop_id=1:1174
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: try https://....

Comment: @AliMaleki, I don't know how to receive the data and check its results is successful or failed

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery AJAX` Method is to load data from external website by calling APIs, and get the response in `JSON` or `XML` formats. this example shows you how easy it is to make such API calls in `jQuery AJAX`.something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        var validate = Validate();
        $("#message").html(validate);
        if (validate.length == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" + $("#citySelect").val() + "&appid=API-KEY&units=metric",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    var table = $("<p>Weather Description</p>");

                    table.append("<p>City:</p>" + result["name"] + "</p>");
                    table.append("<p>Country:</p>" + result["sys"]["country"] + "</p>");
                    table.append("<p>Current Temperature:</p>" + result["main"]["temp"] + "°C</p>");
                    table.append("<p>Humidity:</p>" + result["main"]["humidity"] + "</p>");
                    table.append("<tr><td>Weather:</p>" + result["weather"][0]["description"] + "</p>");

                    $("#message").html(p);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

To get result `<div id="message"></div>`

Comment: Not the url requested, not the format expected (server send XML), not clean code, nodes not closed...

Comment: @karkael I think you need glasses , request `url` done, `dataType` is format, no needed to use `content type` I dont think you have an idea about ajax see complete example https://www.yogihosting.com/example-jquery-ajax-call-api/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').click(function(){
        var api_url = 'http://example.com/webservices/b2cpincodecheck.jsp';
        var key = '4A8DA5E635656'; 
        var pincode = 604408 ;

        if(pincode=="") {
            alert("please enter the pincode");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url:api_url+"?reqid="+key+"&pincode="+pincode,
                dataType: "xml",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result, status, jqXHR){
                    console.log(loadData(result || jqXHR.responseText))
                }
            })
        }
    });
});

function loadData(xml) {
  var incubator;
  if (typeof xml === "string") {
    incubator = document.createElement("div");
    incubator.innerHTML = xml;
  } else {
    incubator = xml;
  }
  return {
    "response": {
      "result": incubator.querySelector("result").textContent,
      "pinCode": incubator.querySelector("pinCode").textContent,
      "ouCode": incubator.querySelector("ouCode").textContent,
    }
  }
}

function xmlToObject(xml) {
  var incubator = document.createElement("div");
  incubator.innerHTML = xml;
  return Array.prototype.map.call(incubator.childNodes, nodeToObject)
}

function nodeToObject(node) {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    return {
      nodeName: node.nodeName.toLowerCase(),
      attributes: nodeAttributesToObject(node),
      childNodes: Array.prototype.map.call(node.childNodes, nodeToObject)
    };
  }
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return node.textContent;
  }
}

function nodeAttributesToObject(node) {
  var result = {};
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.attributes, function (attr) {
    result[attr.name] = attr.value;
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is two example of data extraction from xml :

1. the function `loadData` get exaclty the field you expect
2. the function `xmlToObject` can help you to walk an XML as if it was a simple JavaScript object.

Please be careful: [jQuery ajax setting `dataType`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) should be empty or the direct format (ie: `"json"`, not `"text/json"`), here you should set it to `"xml"`.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: No needed to mixed up codes with javascript and xml, ajax does all by it self.